# Batch convert images in avif format to dng format - how?

Tags: image-processing

I have a bunch of avif-files that I want to convert to dng - as the software I want to use to work on the images does not accept avif - and I don't want to use jpeg. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can try ffmpeg: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Answer (score 6):

In Lubuntu Noble (a live session of the developing version) I tested imagemagick `convert` and it complains

```
$ convert ttt.avif ttt.dng
convert-im6.q16: no encode delegate for this image format `DNG' @ warning/constitute.c/WriteImage/1310.
```

but the result, the dng file can be viewed by `darktable`.

After that I created a dng file in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, and that file can be viewed by `darktable` too. So `convert` can do it.

---

Install `convert` by

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

---

Convert all .avif files in a directory from avif to dng:

```
for image in *.avif ;  do convert "$image" "${image%.*}.dng" 2>&1 | grep -v 'no encode delegate' ; done
```

---

Edit: `darktable 4.4.2` in Ubuntu family version 23.10, the newest released version, can show dng files. This is an improvement from version 22.04.3 LTS.

[image]

Comment: If that works, then `mogrify -format dng *.avif` should work (no loop needed) I think … `mogrify` comes with [ImageMagick](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ImageMagick.1.html) too.

Comment: dng-Files are created - but apparently they are corrupt in some way. Could not open - tried gimp, gwenview, AfterShot ...

Comment: @sers, My `gimp` cannot manage dng files, but my `darktable` could manage the files created via `convert`. Please let us know if you can [install and] use `darktable` to view the dng files. And I suggest that you also check if the tool you want to use can manage dng files, that are created in some other way, for example directly from raw format pictures with some tool that you rely on.

Comment: @Raffa, You prefer mogrify and I prefer convert :-P (An important reason for me to prefer convert is that it creates new files, does not overwrite the original files, which makes it 'more foolproof').

Comment: It does overwrite the original except when `-format` is set and passed an extension like `dng` ... I know it's unexpected for `mogrify`, but that's a special case and I'm sure it's documented somewhere (as I remember this particularity) but I can't seem to remember where :-)

Comment: Found it https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php (first paragraph) ... However the extension must change for this to not overwrite the original i.e. keeping the same extension like `mogrify -format png img.png` is not what that is.

Comment: @sudodus interestingly my darktable cannot convert these dng-files ... just tried it - it just displays skulls ...

Comment: @sers, You get different results compared to me. (By the way, my android phone can also show the dng files created by convert.) -- Which version of Ubuntu are you running (22.04.3 LTS or some other version)? Which version of imagemagick have you installed and which version of darktable have you installed?

Comment: Furthermore, are you sure that your avif files are good (according to the specifications for avif files)?

Comment: @sudodus sorry, I meant darktable cannot *display* these files - not convert. Imagemagick is an older version - it's from 2021: 6.9.11-60. Ubuntu is on 22.04.3 LTS. Darktable is on 3.8.1. And I can view the avif files all right with gwenview vor instance.

Comment: @sers, I knew since before that darktable in Lubuntu Noble works, but now I also tested the newest released version, Lubuntu 23.10, and darktable can show dng files there too. So a solution for you might be to run Ubuntu version 23.10 (or a community flavour like me, for example Lubuntu 23.10), where `sudo apt install darktable` will install version 4.4.2. This might also solve the problem with other software and dng files for you.

Comment: @sudodus thanks for the hint - so my system is just a bit old now :-)